# Errors installing library libadalang

Tags: ada

I was trying to install libadalang using the script who recommend in this repository https://github.com/AdaCore/libadalang/blob/master/install-lal-and-deps.sh

Honestly, I made some modifications to the script to advance in the installation. I could get to the step when the script start to install libadalang and I get this errors:

[image]

[image]

I was looking in the internet some information but I could not find much about it. Someone have some idea about it??

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give us the output as text, instead of as images?

Comment: It might also be helpful to know which version of GNAT you're using.

Comment: I’m not going to spend much time on this because you’ve also [raised the issue at Github](https://github.com/AdaCore/libadalang/issues/151), where there are people who are much more likely to be able to help.

Comment: Not only which GNAT, which OS (I can see it’s Unix-y). And, what changes did you make to the script?

Comment: The GNAT version is 7.3.0 y Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 0):

At first looks it is setup issue on your side, and it is not related to Libadalang at all. Try to use GNAT Community, don't forgot to update PATH environment variable.